# Real_escape_string() expect parameter 1

Tags: parameters, expect

I have a problem with these code. My error log show me error:

```
real_escape_string() expect parameter 1.
```

I search on Google but I can't find it how can I fix it.

My code

```
$ime_datoteke_zip = $povezava_mysql->real_escape_string($ime_datoteke_zip);
```

Comment: Does the error message ends in "expects parameter 1"? It should continue to say what it expects in regards to parameter 1.

Comment: No the whole error is: real_escape_string() expect parameter 1, parameter 1 string given in var/www/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the information in the comments, I suspect the variable `$ime_datoteke_zip` is not holding a string.

Try calling `is_string($ime_datoteke_zip)` before calling `real_escape_string()`. It returns `true` if the variable holds a string value, and `false` otherwise.

You can also inspect the contents of the variable using `print_r($ime_datoteke_zip)`

Hope this helps!